# Adding two strings to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to check if key and value are same or not in a dictionary, if they are print the count of correct words and if not check how many letters are exact match.

```
eg. {'KEY':'KET'}
the output should be 1 mismatch for Y!=T
```

I tried zip function to add key and value to a new dictionary, but it doesn't add repeating letters to dictionary. like below.

```
word_dict={'PRETTY': 'PRESEN'}  
for key,value in word_dict.items():
    if key==value:
        count_correct+=1
    elif key!=value and len(key)==len(value):
        new_dict=dict(zip(key,value))
        print (new_dict)
```

output of above code is:

```
{'P': 'P', 'T': 'E', 'E': 'E', 'Y': 'N', 'R': 'R'}
```

which is missing one 'T':'S'

I know I could convert key and value in different lists and compare the indexes of both. But I would also like to know if creating a dictionary adds all the values from both strings.

Comment: Dictionary keys *must* be unique, so the `('T', 'S')` key-value pair is replaced by the later `('T', 'E')` pair.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you. I didn't know that. I guess creating lists is better for this situation.

Comment: how do you count when the key length is different from the value length ?

Comment: @jumpy    `elif len(key)!=len(value): count_wrong+=1` . this is a different counter. if length of key and value are not equal, its automatically a wrong word. I need to count mismatch only when lengths are equal to find count of almost correct words.

Comment: If all you want to do is count matching letters then the following should suffice: `sum(map(lambda t:t[0]==t[1], itertools.zip_longest(key,value)))` assuming words can be of different lengths. If it you can assume the lengths will be the same, `sum(map(lambda t:t[0]==t[1], zip(key,value)))` would suffice